# Browser does not recoginize JQuery prettyPhoto() when using asp.net Masterpage

Tags: .net, asp.net, master-pages

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
　
<a href="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/Bkjv9SscotY&hl=it_IT&fs=1?rel=0" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">you tube 
</a> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
　
    $(document).ready(
function () {
    $(
"a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
　
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the line where you include the js file?

Comment: My code is not showing for some reason...let me try updating

Comment: <script src="Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
　
<a href="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/Bkjv9SscotY&hl=it_IT&fs=1?rel=0" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">you tube 
</a> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
　
    $(document).ready(
function () {
    $(
"a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
　
</script>

Comment: you can escape the code using backticks or click the `{}` button in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your folder structure looks like this

```
/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js
/Scripts/someOtherscript.js
/SomeFolder/bob.aspx
sam.aspx
default.aspx
```

If you reference your js file using src="scripts/file.js" it will work on sam.aspx and default.aspx, but it won't work on bob.aspx

When you don't include a leading slash, it looks in your current folder.  So if you reference that script on bob.aspx, it is looking for this file /somefolder/script/file.js

So, to answer your question (assuming I've made a good assumption), you just need to add a leading slash to src="script..   It should be src="/script/...

Answer (score 0):

ResolveUrl is a good option but it is not the ideal solution it would be best if you use the correct path of the js. As you would be using friendly url's then take it from the root and use ~ sign it basically tell's the server to start from root of the folder so even though you have published the app earlier with one less folder lets say inetpub/wwwroot/AppName/WebUI/

and now changed it to inetpub/wwwroot/AppName/ your app wont crash and any time you get a similar error just open the source of the page on the browser and then click on your js file links if you are able to navigate to the js file great else there could be other scenario's like authentication is setup and iis is not allowing you to access it .